# How to allow a trade only when a new candle opens

Tags: charts, finance, stock, algorithmic-trading, quantitative-finance

I am new to coding and I have this issue with my code that I cannot figure out how to fix. The issue is this: How to keep the time of the current candle in a variable and not allowing a trade until a new time is reached.

I receive data info from Binance API, but I cannot figure out how to write this into code. Any ideas?

I dataframe with my Time column but when I try to access it I get the message: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Time'. And everytime I run my code I get filled on the live price, not on the bar "Open".

Here is the func for the data:

```py
def getdata(symbol):
    frame = pd.DataFrame(client.get_historical_klines(symbol, '1m', '100 minutes UTC'))
    frame = frame.iloc[:,:6]
    frame.columns = ['Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Price']
    frame.set_index('Time', inplace=True)
    frame.index = pd.to_datetime(frame.index, unit='ms')
    frame.Price = frame.Price.astype(float)
    frame = frame.astype(float)
    return frame

df = getdata('BTCBUSD')
```